# JBoss - how do I programmatically load a jar? KieSession is NULL

Tags: java, jboss, kie

I have a jar file that from a Windows command line can dynamically load two jars from different path locations via 'java -jar myTest.jar'. One of the jars contains my .drl files and the kmodule.xml. The jar runs successfully from the command line as evidenced by the logs.

```
[main] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject - Found kmodule: jar:file:/C:/BPMPOC/rules/target/rules-0.0.1.jar!/META-INF/kmodule.xml
[main] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added: ZipKieModule[releaseId=org.krtest:rules:0.0.1,file=C:\BPMPOC\rules\target\rules-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]
I am in Rule1!
I am in Rule2!
```

But, after copying the same jar to my JBoss deployments folder and executing standalone.bat my KieSession is NULL. I create the KieSession from the following line of code:

```
KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("HelloWorldKS");
```

I have tried multiple ways of dynamically loading the jar files. Each one successfully works from the command line but not when deployed to JBoss.

Added below on request:

kmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
  <kbase name="HelloWorldKB" packages="org.krtest.rules.helloworld">
    <ksession name="HelloWorldKS"/>
  </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Initialization code

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer(DroolsTest.class.getClassLoader());
KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("HelloWorldKS");
```

Comment: Is `HelloWorldKS` the name you placed in the `<ksession>` tag of your kmodule.xml file ? Or the name you placed in the `<kbase>` tag of your kmodule.xml file ? According to your code, `HelloWorldKS` should be the name of your session, not of your knowledge base. I'm assuming your `kc` variable holds a properly initialized `KieContainer`, could you provide the initializing code and your kmodule.xml file ?

Comment: Done, see above.

Comment: Your `kmodule.xml` seems fine. Your initialization code however cannot compile. You are assigning an object of type `ClassLoader` to a `KieContainer` variable. Did you copy-paste correctly your code ?

Comment: I did not copy-paste correctly. When I get to work I will correct.

Comment: Modified post. Thanks.

Comment: You may try to remove `DroolsTest.class.getClassLoader()` from the `getKieClasspathContainer()` call. Besides this parameter that I do not have in my code, your initialization code seems ok. And your session name does match between kiemodule.xml and `newKieSession(...)` call.